# Selberg's Symmetry Formula

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

I'm going through a proof of the Prime Number Theorem and the derivation of Selberg's Symmetry Formula. However, in it there is one step that is perplexing me. Would anyone be able to help explain why this is true?

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{d^{\prime} \leq \frac{x}{d}} log^2(d^{\prime}) = log^2(\frac{x}{d}) - 2xlog(\frac{x}{d}) + 2x + O\left(\displaystyle\sum\limits_{d \leq x} log^2(\frac{x}{d})\right)$

This apparently derives from:
$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n \leq x} \frac{log(n)}{n} = \frac{1}{2}log^2(x) + C + O\left(\frac{log(x)}{x}\right)$

I don't see how. If I can get this step, then I understand the entire proof which would be awesome!

Edit: I can derive the second equation. If possible, I'm after help with the first.

Edit 2: After thinking about this for a couple of days, I've just realised an easy explanation and it doesn't require the second formula at all. You can just bound it with integrals of log^2.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sum of interest i.e., $S_x:=\sum_{n=1}^x \frac{\log(n)}n$. Note that $\frac{\log(y)}y$ for $y\geq 3$ is a monotonically decreasing function of $y$.  Using this one can show that  for $x\geq3$

$$S_x-S_2\geq \int_3^x dy\ \frac{\log(y)}y\geq S_{x+1}-S_3\ .$$

Carrying out the integral, we get

$$S_x-S_2\geq \frac{\log(x)^2}2- \frac{\log(3)^2}2\geq  S_{x+1}-S_3 \ .$$

Thus
\begin{align}
S_x-S_3-\frac{\log(x)^2}2 +\frac{\log(3)^2}2&\leq \frac{\log(x-1)^2}2 -\frac{\log(x)^2}2\\
&\lesssim  - \frac{\log(x)}x + O(\log x/x^2)\ ,
\end{align}
This proves the required bound for the second relation with $C=S_3-\frac{\log(3)^2}2$.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, this proves the second formula? If so, I already know how to do that, I just don't understand how it applies to the first equation. How would you use it to prove the first equation?

Comment: I corrected an error in my inequality sign. Yes, I have proved only the second inequality and not the first one. Let me think a bit about the first one.

Comment: I know the feeling. :P It's had me puzzling for hours now. I still have no idea how to do it.

Comment: I am not a number theorist and so don't know about Selberg's formual. Does $d|x$?

Comment: See here: http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2006/PAPERS/Balady.pdf (section 4 in particular)

Comment: That says exactly the same thing. Both the book I'm reading and that link say it follows from the second equation. I don't understand "how" you get it.